# Why would 000 on /etc/shadow permissions lead to me not being able to use passwd?

Tags: centos, permissions, root, passwd

Basically, I decided to change the password on the VM I use for work which runs CentOS 7. Entering a new password in literally every case (user runs `passwd` himself, user sudos passwd, `sudo su` and then run `passwd` for root, `sudo su` and then run `passwd` for user) ended in an

```
authentication token manipulation error
```

Running `passwd -u` returned

```
Error replacing /etc/shadow: Operation not permitted.
```

Basically any command that interacted with `/etc/shadow` couldn't interact with it until I gave in and changed the permissions of `/etc/shadow`, at which point it all worked perfectly.

Here are relevant permissions and ownerships

```
ls -ld /etc /etc/shadow /bin/passwd /sbin/unix_chkpwd

-r-s--x--x.   1 root root 27856 Apr  1 06:57 /bin/passwd
drwxr-xr-x. 104 root root  8192 Aug 18 22:08 /etc
-rw-r-----.   1 root root   828 Aug 18 12:59 /etc/shadow
-rwsr-xr-x.   1 root root 36272 Apr  1 07:00 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

Keep in mind `/etc/shadow`'s permissions were changed manually by me.

All over the internet people are saying you should never change `/etc/shadow` permissions from the 000 they are out of the box on CentOS 7, and that programs like `passwd` do not need those permissions to work with the file, but this simply isn't true in my case.

Why?

Comment: Please run this and add it to your question `ls -ld /etc /etc/shadow /bin/passwd /sbin/unix_chkpwd`

Comment: -r-s--x--x.   1 root root 27856 Apr  1 06:57 /bin/passwd  
    drwxr-xr-x. 104 root root  8192 Aug 18 22:08 /etc  
    -rw-r-----.   1 root root   828 Aug 18 12:59 /etc/shadow  
    -rwsr-xr-x.   1 root root 36272 Apr  1 07:00 /sbin/unix_chkpwd  
@roaima for some reason I'm unable to format this comment correctly. This is the result of the run. Keep in mind /etc/shadow's permissions were changed manually by me.

Comment: Please don't put updates in comments. Instead do what I asked and [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/605059/edit)

Comment: If you are not running on a normal system (VM would be normal for this case) but for example in a container, you might have additional limitations. What is your environment? (if needed install the package `virt-what`)